# How to integrate free or reduced products in mysql scheme?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

I would like to add the support of reduced or free products in my MySQL database.

This is the current table structure:

**products**

```
+----+------+------+-----+-------+
| id | abbr | name | net | gross |
+----+------+------+-----+-------+
```

**invoices**

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | created_at | paid_on |
+----+------------+---------+
```

**invoices_products**

```
+------------+------------+
| invoice_id | product_id |
+------------+------------+
```

The most simple option is to add a duplicated product entity with other pricing however as I got no big data on the database I would like to take an advanced approach which does not included duplicated data.

Comment: Given this schema, the price isn't a component of the product (where it would have to be shared with all invoices), but rather of the invoice_product (where it can be changed for each invoice).

Comment: Good idea. However this would make it hard to change the price somewhere central (e.g. the price would have to be managed by the application logic each time). I thought more about some "reduction" column. This could be optional and decrease the price. However still not 100% convinced

Comment: You could have a central price (basically the MSRP) and apply your discounts when the items were added to the invoice.  If you wanted to change your schema further, you could have a product_discount table, with  a start/stop date, absolute or percentage discount, etc.  Lots of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion I got from my daddy who has knowledge about accounting is really smart:

In addition to the articles/products table you need to create a prices and a conditions table:

**prices**

```
+----+------+-------+-----+------------+
| id |  net | gross | net | product_id |
+----+------+-------+-----+------------+
```

**conditions**

```
+----+------+-------+-----+------------+
| id |  net | gross | net | percentage |
+----+------+-------+-----+------------+
```

We could now linke a price entity to a product and then move conditions on to it. This would avoid entites containing double data and it would allow flexibilty towards having multiple conditions applied to a product.